# Xcode show warning if a var is used

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on a project where I need to use a specific Calendar: `Calendar.german`, no matter which are the user preferences.

I want to prevent future developers working on that project to use `Calendar.current`. 
Is there a way to override `Calendar.current` to show a warning to point them to the right one (e.g. like Apple does with deprecation messages) ?

A different approach would be to override `current` to return `german`:

```
extension Calendar {
    static var german: Calendar {
        var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
        calendar.firstWeekday = 2
        return calendar
    }

    static var current: Calendar {
        return german
    }
}
```

But I really wonder if it is possible the "warning" thing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mark the method as deprecated and add some comment.

```swift
@available(*, deprecated, message: "use german")
static var current: Calendar {
    return german
}
```

This shows warning `'current' is deprecated: use german`

Comment: But this uses undefined behavior. Extensions are not supposed to be used to override existing functionality. From the [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) chapter of the Swift book: *"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality."*.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to create your own `current` property in a `Calendar` extension, like you did here, and *mark that as deprecated*:

```
extension Calendar {
    static var german: Calendar {
        var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
        calendar.firstWeekday = 2
        return calendar
    }

    @available(*, deprecated)
    static var current: Calendar {
        fatalError() // this implementation can be arbitrary
    }
}
```

Note that this is actually making use of [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2935), so it might stop working in the future.

Another way is to use the `#warning("message")` syntax to issue warnings. But this will only issue the warning at the line where you're written it, but it could still serve as a way to tell future developers not to use `Calendar.current`. Just put a

```
#warning("Don't use Calendar.current!")
```

somewhere and everyone would be able to see it in the error list.

Comment: But this uses undefined behavior. Extensions are not supposed to be used to override existing functionality. From the [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) chapter of the Swift book: *"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality."*.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I know this behaviour is caused by a bug. I've added a note.